# How to prevent external users from viewing document files

Tags: security, coldfusion

I've built an online system that allows users to download PDF files using ColdFusion. Users have to log in before they can download the files (PDF & Microsoft Office documents). (This application is only for our company staff.)

However, only today I found out that anyone with internet access can view the files. With only certain keywords such as 'Medical Form myCompanyName' in a Google search, they can view the PDF files using the browser.

How can I prevent this?

**UPDATE**
this is what my problem is. i've created a folder for all of the PDFs file. each of the files is called using ID from database. if let's say a user wanted to view Medical Form, the link would be: http://myApplication.myCompanyName/forms.cfm?Department=Account&filesID=001.

if the user copy this url & log out from system, he/she will not be able to view this file.(login page will be displayed)

However, without the url, other internet users sstill can view the pdf files just by search it on the net, and the search engine will gives a link that direct it to the folder itself, without having to login.

Example:
Medical Form's pdf file is stored in a folder named Document. when an internet user search for Medical Form, the search engine will link it to: http://myApplication.myCompanyName/Document/Medical%20Form.pdf

we have lots of PDF files in this folder and most of it are confidential, and for internal view purpose only. in php, we can disable this by using .htaccess. i'd like to know if there's anything like this for coldfusion?

Comment: That shouldn't be possible as the pdf's should be in a directory that the web browser cant get to (outside the web realm).

Comment: @DaleFraser, does that means i have to move the PDF folder outside myApplication?

Comment: Yes, its the easiest way if you don't want Google to index them and people to be able to share links

Comment: I see you've added a bounty for this - was there something inadequate with the answers provided?  They seem fairly comprehensive to me.

Comment: Apparently people think that <cfcontent isn't a good option, so I'm looking for the alternative.

Answer (score 5):

You can send files through the code with single line like this:

```
<cfif isAuthorized>
    <cfcontent file="/path/to/files/outside/of/web/root/Form.pdf" type="application/pdf" reset="true" />
</cfif>
```

ColdFusion FTW, right.

<strike>Please note that handling large files (say, 100MB+) may cause some problems, because files being pushed to RAM before sending.</strike> Looks like this is not correct any more, as Mike's answer explains.

Another option is to use content type like `x-application` if you want to force download.

**UPD**

You want to put this code into the file (let's say file.cfm) and use it for PDF links. Something like this:

```
<a href="file.cfm?filename=Xyz.pdf">Download file Xyz.pdf</a>
```

file.cfm:

```
<!--- with trailing slash --->
<cfset basePath = "/path/to/files/outside/of/web/root/" />

<cfif isAuthorized AND StructKeyExists(url, "filename") 
      AND FileExists(basePath & url.filename) 
      AND isFile(basePath & url.filename) 
      AND GetDirectoryFromPath(basePath & url.filename) EQ basePath>
    <cfcontent file="#basePath##url.filename#" type="application/pdf" reset="true" />
<cfelse>
    <cfoutput>File not found, or you are not authorized to see it</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

**UPD2**

Added `GetDirectoryFromPath(basePath & url.filename) EQ basePath` as easy and quick protection from the security issue mentioned.

Personally I usually use ID/database approach, though this answer was initially intended as simple guidance, not really compehensive solution.

Comment: hi Sergii. o-kay. so where should i put the code? is that some sort of config file that should be put outside the pdf folder?

Comment: @dygta No, this is just a 'proxy' for downloading the files. See update for details.

Comment: i'm using database approach too. please refer to my updated Question. thanks

Comment: @dygta Aha, now I see it. You cannot disable these using ColdFusion -- these just are not types of files handled by it. I guess you are using IIS, but I don't know the version. Please check out the URL rewrite rules for CFWheels (IsapiRewrite and web.config) for examples https://github.com/cfwheels/cfwheels

Comment: This code is good, but where would I put it? Can it be placed in a CFC so that the `basePath` and `filename` can be passed in as variables?

Answer (score 4):

You need to store your PDF's outside of your web realm.

So lets say the base of your web app is

> /website/www

All http (web) requests are served from there.

> /website/pdf

could be a path where all PDF's are stored. This path isn't accessible via URL as its not served by your web server.

Then in www

you have something like

```
downloadpdf.cfm?file=NameOfPDF.pdf
```

Which does your checks to ensure its an appropiate user and if so serves the document

```
<cfcontent type="application/pdf" file="/website/pdf/#url.file#" />
```

Comment: One note here, the way this is presented opens a security hole in that it would allow a visitor to download pretty much any file on the server.  A better approach would be to pass in the file's ID (from a database) on the URL, check that it's valid, get the filename from the database, THEN use CFCONTENT to serve up the file.  Never trust user input like this.

Comment: Voted down because this suffers the security hole Justin mentions, plus is not a good solution anyhow, for the reasons Mark explains (albeit after your answer, Dale).  People *really* should not have voted this answer up!

Comment: I believe it is unfair to downvote this answer just because it is not comprehensive or not the 'best approach' -- it is still useful. You can 'patch' the security hole and still use this approach. That's why we have comments system here, for making answers better.

Comment: There is no security hole. I specifically called this downloadpdf.cfm which will only serve content from the pdf folder. So the only security hole would be to allow someone to get to PDFs and as I mentioned the downloadpdf.cfm needs to have to checks in place to ensure everything is appropiate.

Comment: Dale, what happens if I pass in ../../any/path/on/the/filesystem/someOtherFile as the file parameter? *That's* your security hole. Sure, this can be protected against by doing a bunch of stuff to ensure one cannot do that, but you don't mention this. So taken at face value, your answer is a poor one.

@Sergii: I didn't downvote it because I didn't like the answer or thought it wasn't as good as some other ones, I downvoted it because it's a BAD answer, and actually dangerous, to boot.

Comment: Seriously @Adam if the code allows that its just stupid, it takes one line of code to prevent it. Or pass in the filename with no extension and add the .pdf or use the id that someone suggested, all easy solutions.

Comment: Dale, the code you posted *does* allow it (so according to your own description, it's "stupid").  If you modify your answer to address these issues, I'm happy to take the downvote off.  As it stands, your answer is a bad one.

Comment: Wrong, I didn't paste the code for the downloadpdf.cfm not a single line. Feel free to offer a solution rather than troll comments.

Answer (score 4):

Using cfcontent, pre cf8, is a really bad idea, as it loads the entire file into memory before transmission. CF8 and later will actually stream from disk, which resolves the memory issue. However if you have large files, users on slow connections, and/or heavy downloads you still have to worry about thread starvation. Each download with cfcontent ties up a thread for the duration of the download.

Depending on your web server you might be able to route around this by using an x-sendfile extension. This allows you to send an http header with the path to a file outside of your web root, and have your web server handle sending the file, freeing up cf to do further work.

Here's an article by Ben Nadel about using mod_xsendfile on apache, http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2170-Streaming-Secure-Files-Efficiently-With-ColdFusion-And-MOD-XSendFile.htm and here's an equivalent IIS7 XSendFile plugin https://github.com/stakach/IIS-X-Sendfile-plugin

Comment: Is it `really` bad idea? Maybe you first should ask the max document size for this specific application? Assuming that all apps sending 720p movies -- that's bad idea.

Comment: Yes it is a bad idea.  Even no low-traffic sites, using `CFCONTENT` to serve files will absorb server RAM and threads very quickly, causing the server to grind to slow down (for *everyone* using the site), or grind it to a halt.  I have first hand experience of this.  It can be mitigated, but on the whole there are better solutions to this problem than using `CFCONTENT`. Whilst one *can* solve this problem with `CFCONTENT`, one should not.

Comment: Dale: I have a link to my LinkedIn page in my profile, so I'm not sure in what way you'd be "exposing me" beyond the public profile I already maintain.  I have neither trolled nor flamed: I have simply pointed out - valid - shortcomings in your mooted solution. These are based on real-world industry experience (of which I have 10yrs, which is neither exceptional nor trivial).  You do not intimidate me in the slightest, however due to its inappropriate nature, if you attempt to threaten me again, I shall report you to the StackOverflow bods immediately.  Grow up.

Comment: Oh and just because it's a *common* solution or a solution that will "work"  (I do not dispute either point there) doesn't make it a *good* solution.

Comment: Mark's given the answer I would have given (use x-sendfile), and the link that Mike posts to Ben Nadel's blog seems to cover it in sufficient detail to not warrant repeating it here.  I also upvoted Sergii's answer because whilst `<cfcontent>` is not the best solution here, he's done a good job of presenting that as an option.  And hopefully people revisiting this question will read the caveats posted in comments regarding `<cfcontent>` and be aware of them before making a call as to which approach to use.

Answer (score 0):

You might checkout the snippet of code for CFWheels SendFile() helper tag http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/function/sendfile

https://gist.github.com/1528113

Comment: Streaming Secure Files Efficiently With ColdFusion And MOD XSendFile http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2170-Streaming-Secure-Files-Efficiently-With-ColdFusion-And-MOD-XSendFile.htm