# Download image from Website Using Coldfusion

Tags: html, download, coldfusion

I am fairly new to ColdFusion. I have the following code that displays the images on the page that I reference on a tutorial which works fine.

When the user selects on any of the images, it will display the image in the browser. However, I would like to allow the user to download the images, rather than display them in the browser.

I am unable to use the HTML5 *download* to achieve what I am doing, due to the fact that the site I am working on is running off on XHTML 1.0.

I found the following approach [File Downloads with ColdFusion](https://www.trunkful.com/index.cfm/2010/8/4/Serving-File-Downloads-with-ColdFusion) but I am not understanding how to apply it. If anyone could guide me to the right direction or show me another approach, I would appreciate it.

Thank You in advance.

```
<cfset filters = "*.pdf|*.zip|*.doc*|*.docx*|.ppt*|*.pps*|*.pot*|*.dot*|*.xls*|*.xlsx*|*.swf|*.rtf|*.png|*.bmp|*.jpeg|*.gif">
<cfdirectory 
    directory="c:\Downloads\Logos" 
    name="myDirectory" 
    action = "list" 
    filter="#filters#"
    sort="name ASC, size DESC"
    >
<table width="80%" border="0" align="left">
    <cfoutput query="myDirectory">
        <cfset FileExt=ListLast(Name,".")>
        <cfif FileExt eq 'pdf'>
            <cfset imgicon = 'pdf-icon-24.png'>
            <cfelseif FileExt eq 'xlsx' or FileExt eq 'xls'>
            <cfset imgicon = 'Microsoft-Excel-icon-24.png'>
            <cfelseif FileExt eq 'docx' or FileExt eq 'doc'>
            <cfset imgicon = 'docx-icon-24.png'>
            <cfelseif FileExt eq 'lnk'>
            <cfset imgicon = 'url-icon-24.png'>
            <cfelseif FileExt eq 'png'>
            <cfset imgicon = 'png-icon.png'>
            <cfelse>
            <cfset imgicon = 'Documents-icon-24.png'>
        </cfif>
        <tr>
            <td width="30">&nbsp;</td>
            <td  class="e"><img src="images/#imgicon#" alt="#Name#" class="float-left"/ ></td>
            <td  class="e"> <a href="ForceDownload.cfm?filename=#EncodeForURL(Name)#">#Name#</a></td>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
</table>
</p>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />   <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />   <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /> <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />   <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />   <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />     
<p class="post-footer align-left">
    <span class="date">
        <cfoutput>#dateformat(Now(),"mmm dd,yyyy")#</cfoutput>
    </span>
</p>
<br />
<br />      
</div>
```

**Update** I created another script and called it ForceDownload.cfm and did the following:

```
<cfset folder = "c:\path\Downloads\Logos\">
<cfif StructKeyExists(url,"filename") && fileExists(folder & filename)>
    <cfset filename = href="ForceDownload.cfm?filename=#Name#">
    <cfset fileInfo = GetFileInfo(folder & filename)>
    <cfset mimeType = getPageContext().getServletContext().getMimeType(folder & filename)>
    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=""#filename#""">
    <cfheader name="Expires" value="#Now()#">
    <cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#fileInfo.size#">
    <cfcontent type="#mimeType#" file="#folder##filename#" deletefile="No">
</cfif>
```

I replaced the following a tag `<a href="Logos\#Name#" >#Name#</a>` with the following a tag `<a href="ForceDownload.cfm">#Name#</a>`

When I did that, there was no errors. However, when I click on any of the images, it goes to a blank page in which does not display the image.

I am not sure how to pass the name of the files to filename

Any help would be appreciated.

**The Error that is showing**
[image]

**Update:**

I updated the hyperlink: `<a href="ForceDownload.cfm:filename=#Name#">#Name#</a></td>`

and I did the following: *

```
   <cfparam name="http://portal/regalnet_test/ForceDownload.cfm?filename=#Name#" default="">
<cfset folder = "\\oc2-web\wwwroot\RegalNet_Test\Downloads\MktgDownloads\Logos\">

<!--- If the path to the file is valid --->
<cfif fileExists(folder & filename)>
    <cfset filename = name>
    <cfset fileInfo = GetFileInfo(folder & filename)>
    <cfset mimeType = getPageContext().getServletContext().getMimeType(folder & filename)>
    <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=""#filename#""">
    <cfheader name="Expires" value="#Now()#">
    <cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#fileInfo.size#">
    <cfcontent type="#mimeType#" file="#folder##filename#" deletefile="No">

<!--- Otherwise, display debugging information (Dev only) --->
<cfelse>
   <cfoutput>
    Sorry, unable to find file: #folder##filename#<br>
      Does the folder exist? #directoryExists(folder)#<br>
    Does the File Exist? = #fileExists(folder & filename)#
   </cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Comment: You need an additional .cfm script to handle the download. That new script would contain the code from the blog entry (be sure to update the folder path). Then create a hyperlink that points to the new script and passes the image file name as a URL parameter named "filename".

Comment: @Leigh Can you show me. Again, I am very new at this.

Comment: Give it a try first :) 1. Copy that exact code into a new .cfm file. 2. Change the text "[ PATH TO YOUR FILES FOR DOWNLOAD ]" to a real file path like "c:\path\yourimages\" 3. Now test the script in your browser by passing the file name of a real image in that directory as a url parameter named `filename`.  For example `http://yoursite/yourNewPage.cfm?filename=someImageFileThatExists.png` .  What is the result?

Comment: @Leigh I have posted what I have done. Instead of allowing the user the option to download the image, it goes to a blank image page. I am guessing it is referencing the image incorrectly

Comment: (Edit) Almost there. A) The folder path should be absolute, ie "c:\path\to\Logos\", not relative ie "\Logos" (be sure it ends with a trailing "\"). B) Also, the href needs to include the file name as a URL parameter. You do that by appending a `?` to the URL, followed by the parameter name and value, ie `?paramName=paramValue`. Since the expected parameter name is "filename", change the href to this and it should work: `href="ForceDownload.cfm?filename=#Name#`.

Comment: @Leigh Yes I have tried that. it still displays a blank page. Does not give the user the option to download the image. I believe the #Name# is not the right approach to get the name of the images.

Comment: (Edit) No, I verified it works fine (as long as the folder and image exist). If you are getting a blank page that means it is not receiving a url parameter named "filename" OR the file does not exist. See my answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142305/discussion-between-leigh-and-roberto-flores).

Comment: @Leigh: I figured out to remove the error. However, I am unable to download the error. I have updated my question

Comment: What is the actual error message? May need to disable any error handlers to see it on screen, or check the log files.  I noticed you switched to a UNC path, which is a different ball of wax. Permissions are most common issue with UNC paths.

Comment: @Leigh When I click on the image, it stalls. It shows on the browser the following: ieframe.dll. I think the filename in the forcedownload.cfm is causing it

Comment: Why did you switch back to the old code? :/

Comment: @Leigh The old code appears to not through errors I was seeing before. When I hover over the attachments, I can see the files name. But now it is showing the error that I mentioned. I also switched to the new code and it still through the ieframe.dll issue

Comment: Sorry, but I am out of ideas. It is a little hard to follow what you are doing at this point :(

Comment: @Leigh :( I see. Okay, um thank you for your help. I am not sure what I am doing wrong based on what I did following your instructions. I posted what I did and not sure why it isnt working

Comment: @Leigh : The error I am getting is the following: "Variable NAME is undefined. " it is based on the cfparam name field

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. The code is referencing a variable that does not exist in the code. It also does not exist in the original example (or mine for that matter). So it is something you added to the code.  An S.O. thread really is not the right place for extended comments. This would be a lot easier (and faster) to resolve in "chat" :-)

Comment: @Leigh: Thank you for your help. I was able to figure out what was the issue. I need to use #url.param#

Comment: Glad to hear you got it all sorted out.

Answer (score 1):

Which operating system and web server are you using? (You didn't indicate in your question.)  If the files are in a publicly-accessible path, you could add a rule.  We've added the following IIS web.config file to sub-directories that host high-resolution images available for "download only".  We prefer this approach rather than using a valuable ColdFusion thread to deliver static files on slow or abusive (ie, DoS) requests.  (We've encountered bots repeated requesting static files like this and then aborting mid-download after they've determined that it's a file. At this point, it's already too late for ColdFusion as its already loaded the entire file into RAM, encountered a delivery error, aborted and logged the error.)

***NOTE:*** We only use CFContent when the content is either personal & password protected or not already located in a publicly accessible web path.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Content-disposition" value="Attachment" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Regarding the HTML5 `download` attribute, some browsers may still honor the attribute even if the doctype isn't correctly using HTML5. If you are worried about validation services, you may be able to get away with adding the attribute after page load using javascript.

Comment: Valid points. Honestly, I just assumed this was a learning exercise.

Comment: The question was how to force a download in the absence of the HTML5's AHREF "download" attribute.  While it's "possible" to do it using ColdFusion, it's not recommended and will negatively impact the entire ColdFusion environment... especially after search index bots start following the links with multiple simultaneous requests.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I recommended added "XSendFile" support to ColdFusion... so files in protected, non-public paths can be served to end customers using the web server instead of ColdFusion.  This was asked in 2011, but I don't think an easy/native solution exists. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652981/how-to-prevent-external-users-from-viewing-document-files/

Comment: (Edit) Yeah, I got that (and do not disagree) but still sounded like a learning exercise to me. Could be wrong though {shrug}. @RobertoFlores  - If this is for something more than just your own edification, go with James' suggestions. It is good to learn how the tag works (if that is what you are after), but it is not necessarily the best tool for the job.